# Getting Right Cell Name of current Cell VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have current cell name like `B7` i want to get cell name of the cell right to current cell for example in this case the result will be `C7`. How can I achieve this
This is what I have tired but its not working

```
CellName = "B7"
ValueCellName = Right(Range(CellName)).name
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using offset function:

```
valuecellname = Range(cellname).Offset(0, 1).Address
```

Comment: + 1 Answers OP's actual question :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print GetrightCell("B7")
    Debug.Print GetrightCell("XFD7")
    Debug.Print GetrightCell("ADIL1234")
End Sub

'~~> Function returns the right cell if there is one!
Function GetrightCell(CellName As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Range(CellName).Column <> Columns.Count Then
        GetrightCell = Range(CellName).Offset(0, 1).Address
    Else
        GetrightCell = "There are no more cells to the right of this cell"
    End If
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    GetrightCell = "Invalid Cell Name"
End Function
```